# R Models with Factors in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I'm attempting to build a model for sales in R that is then integrated into Tableau so I can look at the predictions as they relate to the actual values. The model I'm building for sales is in R, and I'm trying to integrate it into Tableau by creating a calculated field that uses the model to give the predicted value for each record using the SCRIPT_REAL function in Tableau. The records are all coming from a MySQL database connection. The issue that I'm having comes from using factors in my model (for example, month).

If I want to group all of the predictions by day of week, Tableau can't perform the calculation because it tries to aggregate each field I'm using before passing it into the model. When it tries to aggregate month, not all of the values are the same, so it instead returns a "*". Obviously a prediction value then can't be reached because there is no value associated with a "*". Essentially what I'm trying to do is get a prediction value for each record that I have, and then aggregate those prediction values in various ways.

Comment: I'm not sure what the expectation in the Tableau-user community might be but in the R-user community you are expected to post data and code. (You are also asked to do [and describe] your own searching efforts, so it's not clear you've done that either: http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/whitepapers/using-r-and-tableau )

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I can understand a little bit better what you're talking about. A twbx with dummy data (and even dummy model, but that generates the same problem you're facing) would help even more, but let me try to say a couple of things

One thing that is important to understand is that SCRIPT functions are like table calculations, i.e., they are performed only with aggregated fields, they are computed last (after all aggregations, measures and regular calculations) and you can define the level of aggregation you want.

So, if you want to display values on a daily basis, put your date field on page, go to the day level, and for the calculation partition by DAY(date_field). If you want by week, same thing.

I find table calculations (including R scripts) very useful when they are an end, i.e. the calculation is the answer. It's not so useful (or better, not so easily manipulable) when it's an end, like an intermediate step before a final calculation to get to the answer. That is mainly because the level of aggregation is based on the fields that are on page. So, for instance, if I have multiple orders from different clients, and want to assess what's the average order value by customer, table calculation is great, WINDOW_AVG(SUM(order_value)) partitioned by customer. If, for some reason, I want to sum all this values, then it's tricky. I can't do it directly, as the avg order value is not stored anywhere, and cannot be retrieved without all the clients being on page. So what I usually do is to create the table with all customers, export it to mdb, and reconnect in Tableau.

I said all this because it might be your problem, when you say "Tableau can't perform the calculation because it tries to aggregate each field I'm using before passing it into the model". Yes, Tableau does that and there's nothing you can do about it, but figure out a way around it. Creating an intermediate table in Tableau, exporting it, and connecting to it again in Tableau might be an answer. Performing the calculations in R, exporting it and then connecting to Tableau might be another way.

But again, without actually seeing what you're trying to do, it's hard to say what you need to do

Comment: Ok, let's try again. The model I'm building for sales is in R, and I'm trying to integrate it into Tableau by creating a calculated field that gives the predicted value using the SCRIPT_REAL function in Tableau. The 15 data points was an example, there are far more, but I was trying to explain my problem. The records are all coming from a MySQL database connection. I'll try to edit my original post to make it more clear.

Comment: Updated the answer (and commented here because I was not sure you would receive a notification just because I edited the answer)